# Mirror existing Conan registry from Gitlab to Artifactory

Tags: gitlab, artifactory, conan

As part of a migration process of our Conan registry to Artifactory we probably need to run both side-by-side until all projects have updated their internal processes to Artifactory.

Has someone succeeded with that? My idea was to add an access token in Gitlab (which creates a bot user account) and then add the remote repository in artifactory.

As a URL I tried `https://gitlab.company.org/api/v4/projects/$project_id/packages`
and `https://gitlab.company.org/api/v4/projects/$project_id/packages/conan`

When clicking the *Test* button I get a 404 response notification. Accessing the 2nd URL via the Conan command line works fine.

I guess it is due to Gitlab's reduced Conan-API implementation, but maybe there is a way to make it work anyways.

Comment: Gitlab doesn't implement the ApiV2 protocol that is required for remote and virtual repos. It seems that is would need to be done client side, that is ``conan download`` + ``conan upload``

Comment: Ok, that seems like something I could manage to setup. As a follow-up question, do you know how I could get a list of all available packages of our remote? `conan search "*"` only works for the local cache as far as I understand. I could assemble a full list via "A*" to "z*" patterns, but that still seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: With Conan 1.X ``conan search "*" -r=remote`` should work, doesn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am not sure if that is a general Conan thing or one of the problems of the Gitlab implementation.

Comment: ``conan search "*" -r=conancenter`` will search in ConanCenter central repository, and it works. It is well tested for Artifactory and conan_server, maybe should be reported to Gitlab